# FPS stutter - game running at double FPS specified?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, sdl, frame-rate

I have managed to create a system that allows game objects to move according to the change in time (rather than the change in number of frames). I am now, for practise's sake, trying to impose a FPS limiter.

The problem I'm having is that **double the amount of game loops are occurring than what I expect**. For example, if I try to limit the number of frames to 1 FPS, 2 frames will pass in that one second - one very long frame (~1 second) and 1 extremely short frame (~15 milliseconds). This can be shown by outputting the difference in time (in milliseconds) between each game loop - an example output might be 993, 17, 993, 16...

I have tried changing the code such that delta time is calculated before the FPS is limited, but to no avail.

Timer class:

```
#include "Timer.h"
#include <SDL.h>

Timer::Timer(void)
{
    _currentTicks = 0;
    _previousTicks = 0;
    _deltaTicks = 0;

    _numberOfLoops = 0;
}

void Timer::LoopStart()
{
    //Store the previous and current number of ticks and calculate the
    //difference. If this is the first loop, then no time has passed (thus
    //previous ticks == current ticks).
    if (_numberOfLoops == 0)
        _previousTicks = SDL_GetTicks();
    else
        _previousTicks = _currentTicks;

    _currentTicks = SDL_GetTicks();

    //Calculate the difference in time.
    _deltaTicks = _currentTicks - _previousTicks;

    //Increment the number of loops.
    _numberOfLoops++;
}

void Timer::LimitFPS(int targetFps)
{ 
    //If the framerate is too high, compute the amount of delay needed and
    //delay.
    if (_deltaTicks < (unsigned)(1000 / targetFps))
        SDL_Delay((unsigned)(1000 / targetFps) - _deltaTicks);
}
```

(Part of the) game loop:

```
//The timer object.
Timer* _timer = new Timer();

//Start the game loop and continue.
while (true)
{
    //Restart the timer.
    _timer->LoopStart();

    //Game logic omitted

    //Limit the frames per second.
    _timer->LimitFPS(1);
}
```

Note: I am calculating the FPS using a SMA; this code has been omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is part of how your timer structure is setup.

```
_deltaTicks = _currentTicks - _previousTicks;
```

I looked though the code a few times and based on how you have the timer setup this seems to be the problem line.

Walking though it at the start of your code _currentTicks will equal 0 and _previousTicks will equal 0 so for the first loop your _deltaTicks will be 0. This means regardless of your game logic LimitFPS will misbehave.

```
void Timer::LimitFPS(int targetFps)
{ 
    if (_deltaTicks < (unsigned)(1000 / targetFps))
        SDL_Delay((unsigned)(1000 / targetFps) - _deltaTicks);
}
```

We just calculated that _deltaTicks was 0 at the start of the loop, thus we wait the full 1000ms regardless of what happens in your game logic.

On the next frame we have this, _previousTicks will equal 0 and _currentTicks will now equal approximately 1000ms. This means the _deltaTicks will be equal to 1000.

Again we hit the LimitFPS function but this time with a _deltaTicks of 1000 which makes it so we wait for 0ms.

This behavior will constantly flip like this.

```
wait 1000ms
wait 0ms
wait 1000ms
wait 0ms
...
```

those wait 0ms essentially double your FPS.

You need to test for time at the start and end of your game logic.

```
//The timer object.
Timer* _timer = new Timer();

//Start the game loop and continue.
while (true)
{
    //Restart the timer.
    _timer->LoopStart();

    //Game logic omitted

    //Obtain the end time
    _timer->LoopEnd();

    //Now you can calculate the delta based on your start and end times.
    _timer->CaculateDelta();

    //Limit the frames per second.
    _timer->LimitFPS(1);
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Also this explains your timming of 993, 17, 993, 16... The big number is the actual FPS you want to calculate and the small number is the miscalculated delta.

Comment: Thanks for this!! I'll need to make some changes to how the objects move and how FPS is calculated but this is a great start!!

Comment: Don't mention it. I only noticed it because I've made a similar mistake in the past. You can combined `LoopEnd` and `CaculateDelta` into one function and just get the end time and caculate the delta at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your gameloop is triggered only when SDL_Delay() expired wouldn't it be enough to write:

```
void Timer::LimitFPS(int targetFps)
{
    SDL_Delay((unsigned)(1000 / targetFps));
}
```

to delay your gameloop by the right amount of milliseconds depending on the requested target FPS?

Comment: That doesn't consider the time that the game loop takes to be executed.

Comment: Then substract that time. Shouldn't be that hard. Hint: subtracting _deltaTicks after delaying for a second is wrong.

Comment: I already do subtract this time, hence why I was aware of your fault.

Comment: No you are not. You are substracting the timer delay which is different from the time it takes to render a frame. This is why you get that weired sequence of "long short long" frames.